# How can I run a cscript as administrator with another vbscript?

Tags: vbscript, shellexecute, wsh, createobject

I can use `CreateObject("shell.application").ShellExecute` but can I run a **cscript** as `administrator`? using that? I'm kind of a newbie vbscripter. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `RunAs` command? I posted a solution recently that walks you through getting the proper syntax for executing the `RunAs` command from within VBScript.

[Take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25801174/need-help-in-this-visual-basic-script-launching-a-program-in-silent-mode/25811435#25811435) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The scriptPath is the path to your script you want to run as administrator

The Arguments is the commandline arguments you want to pass to the script. NOTE the Arguments are space separated, if you want to pass an argument that contains spaces you will need to enclose that arguments in quotes [Chr (34) is the quotes]. to do that you will need to write for example. 
 `Arguments= chr (34) & "Hello World" & chr(34)`

```
ScriptPath="Path to your script"
Arguments="Any arguments to pass to the script"

CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "cscript.exe",_
Chr(34) & ScriptPath & Chr(34) & _
" " & Arguments,  _
"", "runas", 1
```